# Replace last line of text in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a `TEXT` column in MySQL table. Lines of text are appended to the end of the field, with `UPDATE` query and `CONCAT` function. Every line ends with `\r\n`.

```
single record field content:
---------------------------
line1
some other line
last line
```

`UPDATE tbl SET field = CONCAT(field, 'last line\r\n')`

Sometimes there is a need to replace the last line with a different string. How can I do it using MySQL `UPDATE` query and string function(s)?

### EDIT

To make it simpler I could store the lines count and increment it every time the new line is inserted.

Comment: Would it not be quicker to replace the entire field with a new string?

Comment: or add each line as a seperate  record?

Comment: It has to be single query and small chunks of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET field = CONCAT(LEFT(field,CHAR_LENGTH(field)-1*CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'\r\n',-2))), 'new last line\r\n')
```

Comment: It's the only way to ensure the last line replaced, even if last two are equals.

Comment: How about storing lines count inside the record?

Comment: If you store the field length before append the new line, you can change that part of the expression: `-1*CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'\r\n',-2)`. I don't think that store the line count will help for a single query.